# MySQL join count from one table with ids from another

Tags: mysql, left-join

I have two tables that make up a full text index of article content for search purposes.  One of the tables is just a primary key associated with a word, whereas the other records the article it occurred in and its location in the document.  A single word can conceivably appear many times in the same document with different locations, so the same word id can occur several times in the word_locations table.

Here are the structures:

words:

```
id          bigint
word        tinytext
```

word_location:

```
id          bigint(20)  
wordid      bigint(20)  
location    int(11) 
article_id  int(11)
```

What i need to write is a query that will find the count of occurrences for each word for any one profile.  I need to preserve a zero value for wordids that don't appear at all, so I assume this needs to be a left join.  However, whenever I try to add a where query to limit off article, any wordids that don't appear at all are not included in the result set.

I have tried:

```
select words.wordid, COUNT(word_location.wordid) as appears from words left join word_location on word.id = word_location.wordid where article_id = %s GROUP BY wordid
```

But this query does not return zeros for words that don't appear at all.

How can I modify this left join?

Thanks in advance!

**EDIT**:

Here is an example data set and the result sets for the different queries.

Example article content:

> Bob's Restaurant is one of the finest restaurants in greater
>   County where you can enjoy the finest Turkish Cuisine.

So the vocabulary table, after being adjusted by the application to exclude stop words, will have in its vocabulary rows for `Bob`, `Restaurant`, `finest`, `greater`, `county`, `enjoy`, `Turkish`, and `cusine`.  (I'm using this actual article since it's the first in the set, so  the ids actually appear starting from integer 1.

The query provided by @Mark Bannister produces this result set:
wordid - word - occurances:

```
128 clifton 0
1   bob's   2
2   restaurant  2
3   one 1
4   finest  3
5   restaurants 2
6   greater 1
9   county  1
12  enjoy   3
13  turkish 6
14  cuisine 1
```

The result set is correct per se - but id 128 doesn't appear in the document at all and is the only thing in the result set with occurance 0.  The goal is to have the entire vocabulary returned with number of occurrences from the document (this is roughly 2500 different words)

My original problematic query from before the edit above actually returned the same result set, but without ANY 0 occurance rows at all.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to include your article selection in your join condition:

```
select words.wordid, COUNT(word_location.wordid) as appears 
from words 
left join word_location on word.id = word_location.wordid and article_id = ? 
GROUP BY wordid
```

Including the restriction on article_id in the WHERE clause effectively turns your left join back into an inner join.

Comment: I think I get what you're saying, but this query seems to only produce one zero quantity result, and I can't seem to determine why that particular one gets returned.  Other than that the rest of the result set is the same as the original erroneous query.  Thanks!

Comment: @DeaconDesperado, can you include some sample data in your question?

Comment: Certainly - an example of the general data or the result set return by the two different queries?

Comment: What happens if you try it as amended above?

Comment: Edited and added the result set the query above returns.

Comment: I meant some sample data for the words and word_location tables.

Answer (score 1):

I would use a subselect instead of a join.

```
SELECT words.id, (SELECT count(*) FROM word_location WHERE word_location.wordid = words.id) as appears
```

Comment: Thanks Ken - adjusted as follows this works and returns the correct set:
|SELECT words.id, (SELECT count(*) FROM word_location WHERE word_location.wordid = words.id and word_location.article_id = ?) as appears from words|  - still wondering if this can be accomplished with the join though.

Answer (score 0):

Bit of a guess this one, but I think COUNT() is just disregarding your nulls, not COUNTing them and arriving at 0. (NULL + NULL != 0)

Look at the IFNULL() function, you might be able to do something like:

`COUNT(IFNULL(word_location.wordid, 0))`

(Disclaimer - I am more used to Oracle's NVL(, ) function hence this is a little speculative!)